# boto3 format and location of credentials file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm just getting started with boto3 and tried the following code:

```
import boto3
boto3.session.Session(profile_name='Credentials')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

If I name the section in ~/.aws/credentials [default], it works fine but if I name it something else, like [Credentials] and specify the profile_name as I did, it fails with

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

I want to be able to specify different profiles in the credentials file but I can't get past this error. Some people have answered this question saying that the section must be [default] but that cannot be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you missed is setting the session variable and calling resource on that session instance.

```
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='Credentials')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Also verify the string 'Credentials' exactly matches the [Credentials] in your ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: That helped but now I get a message that I must specify a region. I have a config file in the .aws directory with the default region set to us-east-1. I know I can make region part of the session but is there anyway to set a default region?

Comment: in your `~/.aws/credentials` add a new line under your profile (in your case [Credentials]) that looks like that: `region = us-east-1` this would save you having to set that region variable in boto3.

Comment: I thought the region was specified in the ~/.aws/config file